# Pandas dataframe has 0 column after `pandas.read_json()` even the json have value

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have JSON file that consist of one json file that consist of 1 object, 36 key, and each key have single value (not a nested object)

```
{
  ...
  "created_at": "Sat Apr 14 11:15:29 +0000 2012",
  "description": "Pemerhati sospol hukum dan ekonomi",
  "is_translator": false,
  "can_media_tag": true,
  "pinned_tweet_ids_str": []
  ...
}
```

I try to read using pandas using `pd.read_json('...')` but i show that pandas has `0 rows × 36 columns` not `1 rows × 36 columns`

Comment: What is your pandas version? Try doing `lines=False` in the parameter. `pd.read_json('your_file',lines=False)`

Comment: pandas 1.5.3, I found a solution
import json

with open('your_file', 'r') as json_file:
    json_data = json.load(json_file)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_data, orient='index').T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell `pandas` what is your JSON format is. This can be achieved by passing [`orient="index"` argument](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) which basically says your JSON is *dict like  `{index -> {column -> value}}`* format.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json("file.json", orient="index")
print(df.T)
```

Comment: I found a solution import json with open('your_file', 'r') as json_file: json_data = json.load(json_file) df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_data, orient='index').T 

but your solution definetely what I'm expected